# Best way to detect changes when values might not exist anymore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, comparison, concatenation

I've been trying to detect changes in multiple inputs on a web page.
To do that, I used a query like this:

```
$(.InputClass).data("InitialValues",$(.InputClass).serialize())
```

(I'm not in front of my code sadly but it should look like this)

Then later I compared the values in .data with the new values and it worked perfectly fine but for one single thing, a GridGiew.

In that GridView, the user can add or remove rows dynamically (adding or removing data). If I save the initial values in the .data, it will be destroyed with the row and both will be undefined (initial and new values). The input I need to check is hidden and the unique value can be accessed using `$(.myNewClass).val()` (as I tried to use a different class for this specific hidden input)

I was wondering what woudld be the best solution.

I tried to concatenate all val() from myNewClass using something like

```
var initialValues = $(.myNewClass).map(Function(x){ 
    return x.val()
})
```

(Again, I am not in fron of my computer, and I am new to javascript and jquery).
It was not working. Intellisense could not see .map (and it crashed).

If there is no better way, could you help me with the way I record the concatenation of my val() values?

If there is a better way, could you please point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is expected result concatenation of `.myNewClass` values or array of `.myNewClass` values ?

Comment: An array of values, or a concatenation of all the values, or a serialisation of all values, to compared a "before" state with an "after" state and detect changes (and eliminate false changes, like if someone added a row then deleted it, it should not be counted as a change, as nothing actually changed).

Comment: _"The input I need to check is hidden"_ How is the value changed ?

Comment: I suppose it does not affect the value, but as I am new to javascript, I tried to include pretty much all informations I had, I was not sure if it could affect the reachability of my selector. I now suppose it won't. :P

Comment: Not certain if interpret requirement correctly ? Return an array of all existing `.myClass` element values ? _""before" state with an "after" state"_ ? Do hidden values change ? Can describe example of "before" state value , "after" state value ?

Comment: Yes, the hidden value is evaluated from VB.NET code when a new row is created. It is the "event key" we could say. I added it as no other fields could be unique. As an example, I have the date, but a user could delete a row and create another one the same day and it would not be detected. I want to compared the initial list of unique "keys" with the current list when quitting the page.

Comment: Is requirement to compare initial total "rows" to total "rows" at some point before or after "quitting the page" ? What is _"quitting the page"_ ? Are values posted to , stored at server ? When able , can include stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: I am using my method to detect change onUnload and my method to initialize my variables onLoad. But everything else works, only the values I mentioned escape me. I need to compare the values of each row (can be concatenated/serialized/etc.), initial versus current (juste before the unload). If a change occurred, I display a pop-up. This is already working for all other inputs.

Comment: See post . Adjusted `.map()` to return array of values , set at an object `items` , which at `unload` `event` , will have property `currentValues` set to "current" values of `.myNewClass` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At

```
var initialValues = $(.myNewClass).map(Function(x){ 
    return x.val()
})
```

`.myNewClass` should be a `String` , within quotes `$(".myNewClass")` .

`F` at `.map()` callback should be lowercase `f` , to prevent calling native `Function` .

`x` at first parameter of `.map(x)` would be the `index` of the element or object within the collection of elements or objects - not the element ; try adjusting to `.map()` callback function parameters to `.map(function(index, elem))` to correspond to their values within loop.

`x.val()` within `.map()` would return error , as `x` would be the `DOM` element `<input>` , not the jQuery object `$(x)` ; try utilizing `x.value` , or `el.value` to retrieve value of current element within loop

Try opening `console` , clicking "Run code snippet" twice at stacksnippets below . The `alert` does not appear to be called at stacksnippets, though the `error` message displays the contents of `items` at `console`

---

```js
// create `items` object , 
// containing `initialValues` , `currentValues` properties,
// set initially to `undefined` ; set to `Array` 
// at `load` , `unload` events   
var items = {
  "initialValues": undefined,
  "currentValues": undefined
};
$(window)
  .on({
    "load": function() {
      // set `items.initialValues` array
      items.initialValues = $(".myNewClass").map(function(index, elem) {
        return elem.value
      }).toArray();
      console.log("load", items);
    },
    "unload": function() {
      // set `items.currentValues` array
      items.currentValues = $(".myNewClass").map(function(index, elem) {
        return elem.value
      }).toArray();
      console.log("unload", items);
      alert(JSON.stringify(items, null, 4));
    }
  });

  $(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // do stuff
      // remove first `.myNewClass` element "row"
      $(".myNewClass").first().remove();
      // change element at index 3 within `.myNewClass` collection
      $(".myNewClass").eq(3).val(123);
    }, 1500);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="myNewClass" />
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="myNewClass" />
<input type="hidden" value="3" class="myNewClass" />
<input type="hidden" value="4" class="myNewClass" />
<input type="hidden" value="5" class="myNewClass" />
```

See [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) , [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/)